# load text dynamically in javascript using createElement('link')

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, promise

I'm trying to load some scripts, css files, and text dynamically, following [this](https://usefulangle.com/post/343/javascript-load-multiple-script-by-order) example. It works great for scripts and css files, but not when I try to add a link that loads text (see below). I have never tried this before and don't have much experience with promises, so I may be making an obvious mistake.

The following promise to load a css file is fullfilled without problems:

```
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = 'stylesheet';
      link.type = 'text/css';
      link.href = url;
      link.onload = function () {
        resolve(url);
      };
      link.onerror = function () {
        reject(url);
      };
      head.appendChild(link);
    });
  };

  promised = [linkCSS("javascripts/jquery-ui.css")];

  console.log('promisedCSS', promised);

  Promise.all(promised).then(function () {
  }).catch((reason) => {
    console.log(reason);
  });
```

...but when trying to do something similar to dynamically add the following link to the head:

```
<link rel="gettext" type="application/x-po"
    href="javascripts/node_modules/country-region-dropdown-menu/languages/en/LC_MESSAGES/en.po">
```

...which I attempted to do as follows:

```
 function linkGettext(url) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = 'gettext';
      link.type = 'application/x-po';
      link.href = url;
      link.onload = function () {
        resolve(url);
      };
      link.onerror = function () {
        reject(url);
      };
      head.appendChild(link);
    });
  };

promised = [linkGettext("javascripts/node_modules/country-region-dropdown-menu/languages/en/LC_MESSAGES/en.po")];

  console.log('promisedGETTEXT', promised);

  Promise.all(promised).then(function () {
  }).catch((reason) => {
    console.log(reason);
  });
```

There is no error, but the promise remains forever pending. The head seems to look as desired though, so maybe there's something wrong with the resolution of the promise?

How can I add this  link which uses ref='gettext' dynamically, such that the promise is fullfilled?

Comment: you can use `fetch` to get remote content (if allowed)

Comment: @ITgoldman So you mean instead of loading the file in the head, i can load it with fetch? I'm not sure how to do this. I'm utlimately just trying to load this, but dynamically depending on which language i need to to load: https://github.com/geodatasource/country-region-dropdown-menu#usage

Comment: Actually i don't know about the `<link rel="gettext">`. Maybe the getText.js script loads it dynamically itself and all you have to do is just add it to the `<head>`

Comment: Yes, it works fine in the head, but not when i dynamically add it to the head with `createElement('link')`

Comment: and you do that *before* calling the gettext.js script?

Comment: oh, i see---I'm loading the script Gettext.js before using the rel='gettext' link, i am adding both dynamically to the head. (but the other order around doesn't work either). I can see they have this order if i output 'head' to the console.log. If i instead add both to the head directly it works, and the order in which i put them does not matter.  is this your question? (sorry, i'm not very experienced with this)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the suggestion above to load the data with fetch instead of using a link, but I wasn't sure what do then do with the data. Here's what I used to fetch it, but I think I'd have to add a command to run `Gettext` on it, with parameters that ensure that it's then available for the geodata dropdown menu, but I wasn't sure how:

```
  fetch('javascripts/node_modules/country-region-dropdown-menu/languages/en/LC_MESSAGES/en.po').then(response => {
    return response;
  }).then(data => {
    console.log('en_po data here :', data);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('error');
  });
```

So instead of using fetch, I am now adding this link dynamically without waiting for the Promise to be fullfilled. So I just have this below now in the main script (while I load other scripts and links within a `Promise.all(promised).then(function () {...` to ensure they load before the main script starts.)

So far it seems that it doesn't seem to create a problem to just add this link like this:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

let link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'gettext';
link.type = 'application/x-po';
link.href = "javascripts/node_modules/country-region-dropdown-menu/languages/en/LC_MESSAGES/en.po";
head.appendChild(link);
```

The purpose of all this is that now I can determine earlier in the main script which language will be loaded (so `en.po` will be varied depending on context)